# Find Max Value and its index in 3 Dimensional array

Tags: javascript, mapreduce

I want to find the max value and its *outer* index in a n-dimensional array, e.g.:

```
myArray = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
```

I came up with sth like this so far:

```
const highest = myArray.reduce((r, a) => a.map((b, i) => (r[i] > b)), []);
```

Desired Output in this example would be:

```
[8, 2]
```

Comment: Can you share what your desired output is? `[2,2]` ?

Comment: `[8 ,8]` doesn't make any sense here

Comment: HIghest Total Value and Index of Group. Agree and corrected @CodeManiac

Comment: Are all values guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Should be unique if I use more decimals. But not necessarily.

Comment: Then in the event that the max value is duplicated, what would the return look like? E.g, `[[0,8,8],[1,2,8],[3,4,8]]`?

Comment: @TylerRoper it should be `[max value , index of wrt to outer array]` as mentioned by OP in comments

Comment: Understood. For what it's worth, I don't think a worse example could've been chosen if OP had tried haha, though I'm sure it's solely coincidence :) `8` is both the max value **and** it's flattened index. `2` is both the index of the group containing the max in the outer array, AND the index of the max value *inside* the containing array.

Comment: Agree, unfortunate data set. My bad. Thanks for the straitout. I'm in Vipassana Retreat for what its worth or at least it feels like it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce, use the first element's value as default value in reduce accumulator, update if current value is greater than accumulator update it current value from innerLoop and index from outer loop

```js
let myArray = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

let findIndex = (arr) => {
  let max = arr.reduce( (op,inp,i) => {
     inp.forEach(v => {
      if(v > op[0]){
        op = [v, i]
      }
     })
     return op
  },[arr[0][0],0])
  return max
}

console.log(findIndex(myArray))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` method and get the `max` value for each array and check if that value is bigger then the first element in accumulator.

```js
const myArray = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

const highest = myArray.reduce((r, e, i) => {
  const max = Math.max(...e);
  return (!r.length || max > r[0]) ? [max, e.indexOf(max), i] : r
}, [])

console.log(highest)

/*
    8 - max number value
    2 - index of max value in the sub-array
    2 - index of the sub-array where the max value is
*/
```